# How to display all columns while computing percentage missing in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

There are total 146 columns in Dataframe.
Executing below python statement won't display all 122 columns, My requirement is to display all columns.

```py
df.isna().mean().round(4)*100
```

```
Result
ID            0.0
NAME          0.0
CODE          0.0
FLAG          0.0
             ... 
AMT_DAY     19.5
AMT_WEEK    19.5
AMT_MON     19.5
AMT_QRT     19.5
AMT_YEAR    19.5
Length: 146, dtype: float64
```

Comment: You have to add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to allow others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this code at the beginning of your jupyter notebook or your ipython shell. It will ensure that all rows are displayed with all the decimals.

```py
    import pandas as pd
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows',None)
```

Comment: Hi Ishita, Code which you've shared will help in viewing all Dataframe columns while displaying its data. Actually, my requirement is to display all columns while computing missing values percentage for each column. As you can see the result which I've pasted in the main question. out of 146 columns, result is having for few fields where i can see missing percentage.

Comment: Hi Dilip, I have updated my answer based on your edited question. Please check and let me know if if helps.